Python не видит путь к библеотекам виртуального окружения
возникает ошибка при написании программы. Создаю виртуальное окружение командой python -m venv .venv, находясь в директории проекта, активирую его через source ./.venv/bin/activate, устанавливаю туда модули (например scapy) через pip install, pip list выводит установленный модуль, Pylance корректно определяет модуль.
Однако при импорте данного (и любых других, устанавливаемых через pip install) пакета с активированным venv интерпритатор выдает ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'name'. Помогает прописывание в начале программы
sys.path.append(
    "/home/Username/Folder/Python/Project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages"
)

Но это явный костыль, и хотелось бы исправить  ошибку в корне.
Вывод sys.path без ручного добавления site-packages: ['/home/Username/Folder/Python/Project', '/usr/lib/python312.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.12', '/usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Если это имеет значение, то у меня в системе установлен пакет python-is-python3.
which python / which python3 ссылаются на /home/Username/Folder/Python/Project/.venv/bin/python или python3 соответсвенно.
Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос окажется наивным и глупым, на Линуксе сижу недавно

«с активированным venv» — как вы определили что с активированным? Вы добавили метку [visual-studio-code] — если проблема именно в нём, то что вы предприняли, чтобы активировать venv конкретно в Visual Studio Code, а не в каком-то там терминале?

@andreymal, появляется (.venv) в командной строке. Активировал в терминале в самом VSCode. Метку добавил для информативности, если вдруг моя проблема касается именно настроек VS

А импорт-то делаете в том же самом терминале?

@andreymal, да, из того же терминала

@andreymal, сейчас заметил, что импорт из терминала работает корректно, не работает код при попытке импорта стороннего модуля. Видимо проблема в интерпритаторе, однако я явно указывал на ./.venv/bin/python или ./.venv/bin/python3, но ошибка остается

А интерпретатор в самом VSCode выбран или нет? Справа снизу в строке состояния.

@AlexanderLonberg, да, проверял его первым делом

У меня всегда есть такие настройки "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true, "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"}, "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv", "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env". Плю к этому минимальное содержимое файла .env такое PYTHONPATH=.

Вопрос саморешился. Интерпритатор был не виноват, требовалось изменить параметры запуска кода. (условно с run code на run file)
